# Таблица HTML в Django

Tags: html, python, django

Есть такой словарь:

```
dict = {
'columns': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
'headers': ['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4'],
'data': [
    ['111', '222', '333'],
    ['111', '222', '333'],
    ['111', '222', '333'],
    ['111', '222', '333']
]}
```

Как с помощью тэгов HTML и языка шаблонов Django сделать именно такую таблицу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы его для начала перевёл в более удобный для шаблонов вид ещё в python-коде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dic = {
    # согласно логике, если ячейка пустая, то лучше бы об этом предупредить явно, 
    # чем надеятся что Python угадает
    'columns': [None, 'one', 'two', 'three'],
    'headers': ['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4'],
    'data': [
        ['111', '222', '333'],
        ['111', '222', '333'],
        ['111', '222', '333'],
        ['111', '222', '333']
    ]
}
```

Преобразуем `headers` и `data` в `headers[i] + data[i]`.
[Исчерпывающее руководство по map и zip](http://ninjaside.info/blog/ru/funkcii-map-i-zip-i-lambda-python/)

```
rows = [dic['columns']] + list(map(lambda x: [x[0], *x[1]], zip(dic['headers'], dic['data'])))
```

Разберем по шагам эту строчку:

1. `zip(dic['headers'], dic['data'])` объединяем два массива в map его вид будет `[['header1', ['111', '222', '333']], ...]`
2. Создаем объект map по шаблону `lambda x: [x[0], *x[1]]`, `x[0]` - это `'header1'`, `*x[1]` (звездочка впереди означает что мы передаем объекты списка, а не сам список), соответственно `'111', '222', '333'`.
3. Складываем `[dic['columns']]` и map, (конвертируем его прежде в list)

В шаблоне указываем нашу таблицу:

```
<table>
    {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
            {% for col in row %}
                <td>
                    {% if col %}{{ col }}{% endif %}
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```